# Регулярное выражение. Парсинг аргументов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

все никак не могу составить регулярку для парсинга аргументов. Например у меня команда для моей программы:

```
http "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" 443 "Post request"
```

Мне необходимо вытащить все данные из этой команды, результат должен быть примерно таким:

```
[0] => http,
[1] => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/,
[2] => 443,
[3] => Post request
```

Прошу помощи, заранее спасибо.

Comment: `preg_match_all('~"[^"]*"|\S+~', $s, $matches)`, `print_r($matches[0])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Кавычки тоже захватывает. =(

Comment: `preg_match_all('~(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S+))~', $s, $matches)` - `print_r($matches[1])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо, все работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать группу со сбросом индексов захватывающих групп (*branch reset group*):

```
if (preg_match_all('~(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S+))~', $s, $matches)) { 
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/cqryXF/1)

**Подробности**

- `(?|` - начало группы со сбросом индексов захватывающих групп

  - `"` - двойные кавычки
  - `([^"]*)` - Захватывающая группа №1: 0 и более символов, отличных от `"`
  - `"` - двойные кавычки
- `|` - или

  - `(\S+)` - Захватывающая группа №1: 1 и более знаков, отличных от пробельных символов
- `)` - коненц группы.